# App won't run under Android Studio 2.0, after upgrading from 1.5

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.0

I recently upgraded my Android Studio from 1.5 to 2.0. My app would build and run nicely on Android 1.5. Now, when I try run the app on my smartphone, it gives me this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
> 24
```

When opening my project on Android Studio 2.0, a message box appeared, telling me to upgrade my gradle to version 2, which I did. I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Here is the output I get as I try to run the app on my phone:

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2321Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable840Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugUnitTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugUnitTestSources
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 31.987 secs
Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2321Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable840Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:app:transformResourcesAndNative_libsWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
> 24

* Try:
```

Comment: Which Android API and Java JDK versions are you using? You need to put more information.

Comment: Did you do the thing it asked you to try at the end of the log (that's cut off here)?  You can get more info if you run with --debug and --stacktrace, but you'll have to pay more attention to the output.

Answer (score 14):

Try to disable the Instant Run option in Android Studio 2.0

This is helped me.

[image]

Comment: I wasted so much time figuring out the issue. Thank you so much +1

Answer (score 0):

try to uncheck the instant run on settings..  search instant on the settings and youll see it. or maybe you havemt changed the path of your gradle to the new one?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever seen a message box like below when you build your project with Android Studio 2.0 ?

[image: Studio 2.0 update prompt]

If not , watch out for this window which will possibly appear when you build your project with studio 2.0 then update it. that will change your **Gradle-plugin** version to  `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'` and **Gradle-wrapper** to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip` or you can do it yourself .

Visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512622/update-gradle-version-on-android-studio-2-0/36512676#36512676) to know more .

Answer (score 0):

## Delete build dir

Don't disable `Instant Run`! It is useful. Instead, try deleting the contents of your build directory, and then rebuilding.

`appName/build` and/or `appName/app/build`

#### Alternatively, clean build

A less brute force option to try is to clean the build.

`Build -> Clean Project` or `Build -> Rebuild Project`